# Is there a way to play a sound when a query is finished executing

Tags: sql-server-2005

I was wondering if there was a way to play a sound after a query has finished executing in SQL server 2005?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio (or Express) you can get it to beep:

> Tools -> Options -> Query Results ->
>   Play the Windows default beep when a
>   query batch completes

[image: SQL Server Management Studio Beep]